# cross client identity and iOS

Tags: ios, google-oauth

Does Google currently support cross client/platform auth for iOS? We need both our server and iOS app to be authorized to hit Google endpoints.

Instructions described in https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/CrossClientAuth don't really work for iOS.

The only workaround I can think is have the iOS app do the initial user auth and pass the code + refresh token to the server and moving forward the server shares the access token with the app whenever the access token expires.

Answer (score 0):

Need more info about your use case to make a recommendation, but I have found it's easier to drive the initial auth/access-code/refresh-token stuff from the server, and then let the client app request access tokens as required.

To answer your specific question, cross client auth *is* supported for iOS, but iOS lacks some of the convenience mechanisms which apply to the initial auth process.

Comment: @pinoyyid can you give more details about how to implement it in iOS ?